# why call by name doesn't give error as divide by zero in following code?

Tags: pascal

```
begin
integer n;
procedure p(k: integer);
    begin
    print(n);
    end;
n := 5;
p(n/0);
end;
```

Output:
call by value:    divide by zero error
call by name:     5

Comment: This looks like Pascal, not C.

Comment: On a call by value call, the parameter is executed before the function, so `n/0` is executed before calling `p`, which divides by zero. On a call by name call, the parameter is **delayed**, and, as it is never used inside `p` (you're printing `n`, not the parameter `k`), then the division never happens, and no error is risen. Also, this is not C.

Comment: Are you saying that code compiles?  In which Pascal compiler?

Answer (score -1):

Parameter of procedure **P** is **integer**, but when you call it with **n/0**, **n/0** type is real, that isn't compatible.

And in Pascal, your can not create new procedure between **begin end**.

(Your code looks like mixed of C and Pascal)

Sorry about my English :(